# Oracle Apex - Interactive GRID Word wrap for headers and cells without HTML tag

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I have an interactive grid in Oracle Apex tool. I need to wrap the heading without html tag.

Is it possible to do a word wrap on headers and cells ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this CSS (you can put it in the page Inline CSS attribute):

```
.a-GV-table td, .a-GV-headerLabel {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

That works for me.

Comment: Worked for me too :)

Comment: This does not work when using column freezing (from left). The rows are not displayed at the same height.